# How do I send HTTP request on behalf of some other machines in my local network?

Tags: http, routes, ip, sniffing, spoofing

I have a local network, I can monitor all traffics there. Bandwidth for each user is limited, and usually all computers are NOT using their total bandwidth. So, if I can find a way to send requests on their behalf, then I can increase my bandwidth for some special purposes. So, the first question that comes in mind is **How do I send HTTP request on behalf of some other machines in my local network?**

**Note**:Lets mention that if the answer to my request goes to somewhere I'm not, then this wouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: "I can increase my bandwidth for some special purposes" - Right....

Comment: You could use IP spoofing, but then I don't think the request from the server will end up where you want it. Your best bet would be to use an HTTP proxy to a server with low bandwidth usage maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check out iptables (linux command line tool) thiss will easily allow you to do this and if you want you can even fake the ip address to get a response message with arptables... if you're running windows i'm pretty sure netsh will allow for same thing